# How to retrieve all rows from a certain offset up to a certain limit?

Tags: php, mysql, sql-limit

Here is my problem, so far I got this script:

```
$result = mysql_query(
    "SELECT *
       FROM $tableVideos
   ORDER BY VideoTimestamp DESC
      LIMIT 6"
) or die(mysql_error());
```

And that will make it so that I can show the 6 newest uploaded videos to my site.

But how can I have a limit of 6 and start from the 6th newest video and go up to the 12th? In that way I could show 6 videos and make a next button to show the next 6 videos.

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained and the [deprecation process](http://j.mp/Rj2iVR) has begun on it. See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: @Madara It seems the big red box isn't big enough, or red enough `:(`.

Comment: @JamWaffles: Apparently. That's why we put links to it here as well.

Answer (score 5):

You currently have `LIMIT 6` to get the first 6 results.  If you use

```
LIMIT a,b
```

then you will get `b` items starting from the `a`th.

Answer (score 4):

You want

```
LIMIT 6,6
```

Meaning "Start with the 6th entry, and give me 6 more".

**[Read more about it.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/select.html)**

Comment: Thanks! Didn't think it was that simple :)

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $tableVideos ORDER BY VideoTimestamp DESC LIMIT 6,6") or die(mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   Actually Limit function have two paramter : 
     one is limit of record and second is start from where.

    result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $tableVideos ORDER 
                          BY VideoTimestamp DESC LIMIT 6,6") or die(mysql_error());
```